# Get a ball to keep jumping using momentum, and force if necessary

Tags: momentum

To make a ball keep bouncing with momentum, or with force. When a bouncy ball hits the ground, the ground takes some of the momentum. But it doesn't disappear. Would you be able to make the ball keep bouncing with use of a bass speaker. To make the bass speaker store and release its pressure to help the ball gain momentum... Would that be possible? Just like a bouncing bass speaker

Comment: see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veM5nZNBoW8

Comment: @MaxW Its related but it does not answer his question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the collision will not be elastic and so the kinetic energy of the object after the collision will be smaller than that before the collision.  The will also be a loss of kinetic energy due to air resistance.

So you could get you bass speaker connected to a suitable oscillator to be vibrating at such a frequency and with such an amplitude that the energy the object has lost is given back to it by the bass speaker.   In the real world I think that it would be very difficult to do as the video suggested by @MaxW shows.